# Retrieve values after last underscore using python as a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

I am trying to fetch the list of students to get the integers from an array.

Input:

```
list=['table_name_student_1', 'table_name_student_20', 'table_name_student_300', 'table_name_student_4500']

Expected Output: [1,20,300,4500]
```

I tried the `split()` function but I am not able to use it in a list.

```
table_name = 'table_name_student_12345'
id = table_name.split('_')
print(id) -- #Output: 12345
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` and `int` in a list comprehension:

```py
lst = ['table_name_student_1', 'table_name_student_20', 'table_name_student_300', 'table_name_student_4500']

output = [int(x.split('_')[-1]) for x in lst]
print(output) # [1, 20, 300, 4500]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list=['table_name_student_1', 'table_name_student_20', 'table_name_student_300', 'table_name_student_4500']
result = []

for element in list:
    result.append(element.split('_')[-1])

print(result)`
```

try this it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to create a function that splits the string according to a symbol, which is `_` in your case.

```py
def retrieve_int_value(element):
    splitted=element.split('_')
    value = splitted[-1]
    return value

students_list = ['table_name_student_1', 'table_name_student_20', 'table_name_student_300', 'table_name_student_4500']
values_list = []

for element in students_list:
    value = int(retrieve_int_value(element))
    values_list.append(value)
print(values_list)
```

Output: `[1, 20, 300, 4500]`